# Drawing anomaly -- do macros nest properly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

The following code draws edges with arrows to two squares. It seems to me the effect should be identical, but no. The arrow at the "node[alive]" child just touches the child, while the arrow at the "\living" child invades it. It must be that I don't understand something quite fundamental about what macros mean or how they work. Can someone kindly explain?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,thick,
    alive/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5mm,rectangle,draw} ]  
    \newcommand{\living}{node[alive]{}} 
    \node  {} 
        child{[thick]
            child{\living} 
            child{node[alive]{}}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The style definition should be made (afaik) outside the picture, as well the definition of a command.

Comment: I originally had defined "living" in the preface; same result. Clearly it is recognized to an extent because the children are both squares and the same size. As for putting "alive" earlier, what would be the syntax?

Comment: The expansion of `\living` appears to happen too lately.

Comment: @egreg Both rectangles appear identical, e.g. both 5mm, both draw'n. So \living does get expanded. If I modify alive/.style by removing specification phrases -- even down to bare {} -- the anomaly between living and alive persists. I wonder if this might be a bug in tikz.

Answer (score 3):

As egreg states in his comment, the `\living` macro gets expanded too late. Or to speak in TikZ: The parser does detect the `node` inside `\living` too late and doesn’t consider the child to be a node which would result in the edge to be drawn correctly (i.e. the node as the target not the child).

This has been fixed in the CVS version of TikZ already by implementing the usual expander that expands things along the path until it founds (in this case) either a `node`, a `coordinate` or “nothing”. So that this does not end in an endless loop a count is decremented until it hits zero.

In many other cases this usually means that the user has given an erroneous path but since this is actually a valid case here (i.e. `child {}`) it does not raise an error.

The Code below is taken directly from the CVS version of `tikz.code.tex`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@parse@child@node{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar n{\tikz@parse@child@node@n}%
  {\pgfutil@ifnextchar c{\tikz@parse@child@node@c}%
    {\pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgf@stop
      \tikz@parse@child@node@rest\tikz@parse@child@node@expand}}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@expand{%
  \advance\tikz@expandcount by-1\relax%
  \ifnum\tikz@expandcount<0\relax%
    \expandafter\tikz@parse@child@node@rest%
  \else%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tikz@parse@child@node%
  \fi}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@rest#1\pgf@stop{\tikz@expandcount=100\relax
  \def\tikz@child@node@rest{#1}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@c c{\tikz@expandcount=100%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar o{\tikz@parse@child@node@co}{\tikz@parse@child@node@rest c}}
\def\tikz@parse@child@node@n node{\tikz@expandcount=100%
  \let\tikz@child@node@text=\pgfutil@empty%
  \tikz@p@c@s}
\def\tikz@p@c@s{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar a{\tikz@p@c@s@at}
  {\pgfutil@ifnextchar ({\tikz@p@c@s@paran}
    {\pgfutil@ifnextchar [{\tikz@p@c@s@bra}
      {\pgfutil@ifnextchar \bgroup{\tikz@p@c@s@group}
        {\tikzerror{Cannot parse this node}}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->, thick,
  alive/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5mm,rectangle,draw}
]
\newcommand*\living{node[alive]{}} 
\node {}
  child {
    child {\living}
    child {node [alive] {}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It would also work if the command is defined as `\newcommand{\living}{child{node[alive]{}}}` and only `\living` is used after `[thick]`.